# Redirect using .htaccess to remove a part of filename in Apache

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I know there are plenty of questions how to replace part of URL with something else (or nothing) using `.htaccess` but I really suck both in regular expressions and in `.htaccess`.

How can I to convert URL like `/v0/A8B9DEBF512F929144257AEE00262C16/$File/IMG_8819.jpg` to `/v0/A8B9DEBF512F929144257AEE00262C16/IMG_8819.jpg`? (Without `$File/`, instead of `A8B9DEBF512F929144257AEE00262C16` and `IMG_8819.jpg` there may be any combination of digits and letters).

Comment: Some sort of `htacess` regex like this: `[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)$` could help .. _https://regex101.com/r/aU7gD2/1_

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes, this doesn't seem sufficient. Maybe there should be more?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(v0/[^/]+)/\$File/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: This code either doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong. Is there something else to do besides just adding this code to the file.

Comment: `http://123.123.123.123:9090/v0/A8B9DEBF512F929144257AEE00262C16/$File/IMG_8819.jpg` this one. There is something strange in filename in the string. Nevermind that, some stackoverflow bug, apparently.

Comment: Is your .htaccess located in `/v0/` directory? Can you show your full .htaccess in question?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nSQxKT4c

Here's the file. No, it's located one level above, like /v0/../

Comment: So this is a level above `/v0/`? Does `/v0/` also have a .htaccess by any chance? This rule worked fine on my Apache.

Comment: This directory doesn't have its own .htaccess, but I believe it is possible to give it one. Should I? If so, what else must it contain?

Comment: No if `/v0/.htaccess` doesn't exist then don't create it, I've tested this rule on my Apache it redirected `http://localhost/v0/A8B9DEBF512F929144257AEE00262C16/$File/IMG_8819.jpg` to `http://localhost/v0/A8B9DEBF512F929144257AEE00262C16/IMG_8819.jpg`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93138/discussion-between-moorindal-and-anubhava).